# text-align footer HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I got a question:
I want my text "left" to go left and my text "right" to go right and want them both on the same line. 
I have added a `text-align` in CSS but it doesnt work. I have also added a `display:inline-block` so the 2 different `divs` can be on the same line. I also want to add a margin between the border of the website and the text. I tried `width:90%` in CSS but then the text is on the same line anymore.

[My Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsrXc.png)

Here is my HMTL code

```
<div class="footer">
   <div class="footerleft">
      <p>Left1</p>
      <p>Left2</p>
      <p>Left3</p>
   </div>
   <div class="footerright">
      <p>RIght1</p>
      <p>RIght2</p>
      <p>RIght3</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
.footer {
     position:absolute;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: #160a70;
     color: white;
}
 .footerright {
     text-align: left;
     display: inline-block;
}
 .footerleft {
     text-align: right;
     display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you check CSS Flexbox. With the use of flexbox, this thing will be much easier and will be responsive as well. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text-align` won't have any effect in your case because the parent width is the width of child content since you set `display:inline-block`. The text is already close to both edges.

The simpliest solution in this case is to use float and simply add padding to main container to create the space between border. Also change `width:100%` with `right:0` to avoid overflow:

```css
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right:0;
  background-color: #160a70;
  color: white;
  padding:20px; /* For spacing */
}

.footerright {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

.footerleft {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footerleft">
    <p>Left1</p>
    <p>Left2</p>
    <p>Left3</p>
  </div>


  <div class="footerright">
    <p>RIght1</p>
    <p>RIght2</p>
    <p>RIght3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or consider the use of flex which is better:

```css
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right:0;
  padding:20px;
  background-color: #160a70;
  color: white;
  display:flex;
}

.footerright {
  text-align: right;
  flex:1;
}

.footerleft {
  text-align: left;
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footerleft">
    <p>Left1</p>
    <p>Left2</p>
    <p>Left3</p>
  </div>


  <div class="footerright">
    <p>RIght1</p>
    <p>RIght2</p>
    <p>RIght3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or add width to your element and **don't forget** to clear the [whitespace](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/):

```css
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right:0;
  padding:20px;
  background-color: #160a70;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
}

.footerright {
  font-size: initial;
  text-align: right;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.footerleft {
  font-size: initial;
  text-align: left;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footerleft">
    <p>Left1</p>
    <p>Left2</p>
    <p>Left3</p>
  </div>


  <div class="footerright">
    <p>RIght1</p>
    <p>RIght2</p>
    <p>RIght3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it helped, can you also help me with the space between the border and the text?

Comment: @Reginald1234 sure, can you explain more :) you want your text to not extend to border ?

Comment: Yes, so there is a space of for example 20 px between the border of the webpage and the text

Comment: @Reginald1234 check again

Comment: Thanks @temani afif I changed to code a little bit and it worked thanks!